# jQuery: How to hide div based on number value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide a div when a page loads, if the number within the span is 0.

Here's what I tried using, which did not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var x = $("span#number").val();

   if (x = 0){
     $("div#container").hide();
   };    

});​
```

Here's the fiddle I set up: http://jsfiddle.net/Cmsvj/

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For span elements you should use `text()` method instead of the `val()`, also in the if statement change the `=` operator with `==`, currently instead of comparing the value you are assigning the value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var x = $("span#number").text();
   if (x == 0){
     $("div#container").hide();
   };        
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cmsvj/3/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Cmsvj/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var x = $("span#number").text();

   if (+x === 0){
     $("div#container").hide();
   };
});
```

1. Use `.text` instead of `.val` - a `<span>` is not an input element.
2. Use `===` for equality; `=` is for assignment.
3. Use `+` to convert to a number (`.val` returns a string).
4. Select jQuery in the jsFiddle.